# Strftime issue in class or function

Tags: c++, strftime, ctime

i write this code on main, it's just work fine but when i try to put this in function or class method, it's does not work, why?
also when i debug this code, it's seems like not compiling  time_t and struct tmp.

```
const char*  getFormat()  { 
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        char buffer[80];

        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

        strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d.%m.%Y H%:%i", timeinfo);
        return buffer;
}
```

Comment: if this code works fine on its own, then where is the function or class that causes the problem? we cant help you without full context.

Comment: @Yucel_K in function this code not working, but when you extract code on the main, it's work

Comment: Don't post code that works, post code that doesn't work.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, this code doesn't work

Comment: You return a pointer to a local variable `buffer`. `buffer` is rendered invalid as soon as the function exits, so it can't be counted on in the calling function. Instead consider declaring buffer in the calling function and passing it into `getFormat`

Comment: @user4581301, not problem with return, i have try print buffer in the function, it's doesn't work anyway

Comment: "i write this code on main, it's just work fine" - make your mind up.

Comment: As pointed out, this code returns a pointer to an autovariable.  It is broken.

Comment: Recap: Returns pointer to local variable that will be out of scope by the time the caller can use it. Two typos: `H%` -> `%H` and `%i` -> `%I` Fix these and your function should work.

Comment: @NeilButterworth What's the problem? The code works fine in main but not when it's in its own function as shown in the question. And that makes sense, because the problem is a dangling pointer to a local variable. That obviously wouldn't have been a consideration when the whole program was in main.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to summarise what the other commentors have said (EDIT: and to do the job properly), this code works fine:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string getFormat ()
{ 
    time_t rawtime;
    time(&rawtime);
    struct tm *timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    char buffer [80];
    strftime(buffer, sizeof (buffer), "%d.%m.%Y %H:%I", timeinfo);
    return std::string (buffer);
}

int main ()
{
    std::string s = getFormat ();
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
03.10.2018 20:08
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oQxSCfSgwFZ3XLZs)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `strftime`, you probably want to use `std::put_time`. It takes an identical format string, so writing out the current time would be something like:

```
time_t rawtime = std::time(nullptr);
tm *timeinfo = std::localtime(&rawtime);

std::cout << std::put_time(timeinfo, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%I") << "\n";
```

This was added in C++11, so it's been pretty widely available for quite a while now.